# Emacs: Saving and restoring original frame layout (e.g. when working with ediff)

Tags: emacs

In a typical Emacs session I often have only one frame open, and I have it divided into **4** windows forming a **2x2** grid with some specific buffers (files) in each window.

Every time I use `ediff-buffers` to compare two buffers, Emacs takes my existing frame, and re-splits it into two windows vertically (which I can choose to hortizontal by subsequentially pressing `-`). However, when I quit the `ediff` session, Emacs does **not**  automatically restore the original layout of windows in my frame.

With this my questions are:

1. Is there any way to automatically restore my original layout?'
2. Even better, how can I have `ediff-buffers` use a **new separate frame** just for the `ediff` session and close it automatically when I quit the `ediff` session?

Comment: Please re-write the question using Emacs' terminology? Emacs has one or more *frames*, each of which contains one or more *windows*, with each window displaying a single buffer. You create new windows by splitting old ones (e.g. `C-x 2`). You create new frames with, e.g., `C-x 5 2`. At first I thought you had just substituted "pane" for "frame", but in the end I couldn't be sure, as you talked about "re-split[ting a pane] into two panes vertically". As ediff provides some options around window/frame usage, having a more precise question will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks phils. I was actually aware of this distinction, but used the `pane` instead of `frame` accidentally. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: My answer has been updated to handle the new semantics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set up functions on the entrance/exit hooks for ediff to save/restore the window configuration, as well as create a new frame.  This seemed to do the trick in Emacs 24.3 - I don't see why it wouldn't work in older versions:

```
(defvar pre-ediff-window-configuration nil
  "window configuration to use")
(defvar new-ediff-frame-to-use nil
  "new frame for ediff to use")
(defun save-my-window-configuration ()
  (interactive)
  (setq pre-ediff-window-configuration (current-window-configuration))
  (select-frame-set-input-focus (setq new-ediff-frame-to-use (new-frame))))
(add-hook 'ediff-before-setup-hook 'save-my-window-configuration)
(defun restore-my-window-configuration ()
  (interactive)
  (when (framep new-ediff-frame-to-use)
    (delete-frame new-ediff-frame-to-use)
    (setq new-ediff-frame-to-use nil))
  (when (window-configuration-p pre-ediff-window-configuration)
    (set-window-configuration pre-ediff-window-configuration)))
(add-hook 'ediff-after-quit-hook-internal 'restore-my-window-configuration)
```

Comment: Great solution. Minor fix: I think the second last line `(set-window-configuration pre-ediff-window-configuration)))` needs an extra closing bracket.

Answer (score 5):

On a related note (though you asked about restoring a window configuration and not a frame configuration):
Recent development snapshots of Emacs 24 let you persistently save and restore the current set of frames. See the new library `frameset.el` and the updated library `desktop.el`. Be aware that this is currently being worked on, so it is liable to change in the immediate.

Answer (score 4):

At least in emacs >= 25, you can use `C-x r f <register>` to store the **frame layout** into a register. `C-x r j <register>` can restore it (Note: after working with a restored frame, you might need `C-x 5 0` to quit, rather than the normal `C-x C-c`).

This is extremely helpful when I use emacsclient to connect to a long-living emacs daemon. The stored frame layout can live through the daemon's life time.

You can also use `C-x r w <register>`. But stored window layouts can only live within the same emacsclient session. After you quit emacsclient, they are gone.

Answer (score 3):

See the [Emacs manual section on registers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Configuration-Registers.html#Configuration-Registers).  You can save your window configurations to a register, run ediff, and then restore the configuration.  The default bindings are `C-x r w R` to 'write' the register, and `C-x r j R` to 'jump' to the register.  You could rebind them accordingly if you plan on using this feature frequently.

You can also write your own function that creates a new frame and runs ediff.  It will take some tweaking because ediff reads the file names from the minibuffer, but it should be straightforward.